# Upgrading of SSIS packages from 2008 to 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2014

We have more than 100 packages running sql server 2008 and trying to upgrade in 2014.I have searched in internet but none of them have complete solution.

The way I have tried to done it was
Create the SSIS project in Sql server data tool in 2014 and add exitsing package of 2008 and upgrade.I don't this it works.

Can some help providing complete steps to upgrade SSIS package in 2008 to 2014.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: what exactly the challenge or error you are getting ? Have you tried to upgrade using Dtexec utility ?

Comment: @Sanjya--Warning arises for script task : "Warning at SCR_BUILD_COMPONENTS [SCR_BUILD_COMPONENTS]: Found SQL Server Integration Services 2008 Script Task "ST_42d36c13f7344a47877c6db9f713bfa9" that requires migration! ". Does the script task is also upgraded or not.If not how we can do it. -- 
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding the packages and clicking on upgrade on individual packages is a cumbersome activity. What I would suggest is in the new solution that you have created, copy and paste all your SQL Server 2008 packages. Right-Click on 'SSIS Packages' and choose 'Upgrade All your Packages'. The wizard will kick in and give you a good break-up of all the changes, successful or failed ones if any.

However, if your packages are spread across multiple solutions, then you would need to individually open the solutions from SSDT which then prompts you to upgrade the packages for each solution.

Ensure that you have taken appropriate backup of your packages before you proceed with the activity.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Kindly mark it as answered so that other questions can be tended to.

Comment: I copied package but it is no shown in solution explorer.But we can do "Add  existing package "  which upgrade package still warning arises for script task : "Warning at SCR_BUILD_COMPONENTS [SCR_BUILD_COMPONENTS]: Found SQL Server Integration Services 2008 Script Task "ST_42d36c13f7344a47877c6db9f713bfa9" that requires migration! ". Does the script task is also upgraded or not.If not how we can do it. --Thanks